# LaravelInstaller package doesn't work if .env has no db parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to add a configurator so that after downloading my project and unpacking, the user could go to / install and configure the .env file.

I use this package:

https://github.com/RachidLaasri/LaravelInstaller.

But when I try to open a project without database-related parameters in `.env` file - it shows an error.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry but if you don't show us your code or what's your progress we can't help you.

Comment: Just go to the package and read all the issues + post your own there, I doubt anyone is going to help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem was with my `AppServiceProvider`, not with the package.**

My app provider had an action with the database, so I wrapped it in the `if` statement:

```
if(env('DB_CONNECTION') !== null) {
   // my db actions
}
```

Comment: Is this the solution to your problem?

Comment: Also, it's better to do it with ```config``` helper, instead of ```env```